# SOQL query for extracting attachments related to Opportunities

Tags: salesforce, attachment, soql

I am a Dynamics admin with little knowledge of Salesforce data export. Is it possible to download all attachments related to opportunities using a SOQL query on the data loader. I am only able to download all attachements related to the org, and that is taking way too much time.

Thanks